# Booting a Mac clone from a partition on a usb 3 external drive

Tags: macos, backup, disk-utility, catalina, bootable-disk

I'm unable to boot a MacBook clone from a partition on an external drive.

I'm in the process of finally upgrading the OS of my mid-2012 MacBook Pro from Yosemite to Catalina, and need to make a bootable clone backup of my Yosemite machine.

Using [this youtube vid as a guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ivGKx2ec9UE), I followed this process:

1. repaired + verified the MacBook HD  with First Aid in Disk Utility and ran an Apple Hardware Test. Everything a-ok.
2. I created 550 GB, OS-extended journaled, partition on a Seagate external HD with a GUID partition map scheme to house a clone of my MacBook's internal HD (~500GB)
3. Holding cmd+R, I started my MacBook in Recovery Mode
4. In Disk Utility  I selected the 550GB partition from the left-side menu, then Restore... from the Edit menu
5. In the "Would you like to restore to '550GBpartitionName' ?" dialog,  I selected my internal Mac HD in the "Restore from:" dropdown menu, then clicked the "Restore" button.
6. After a long time, what appeared to be a clone of my internal HD (both had the same name) appeared in the partition of the external drive.
7. I restarted, now on internal HD, and in System Preferences>Startup Disk I selected the external disk partition (the only other option besides the internal HD itself) from the list. Despite this, upon restart, the Macbook booted again on the internal HD.
8. When I restart and hold down the option key, opening Boot Manager, the internal Mac HD is the only startup disk option available :-/

thanks for any help!